# Compiler warning when using boost::blank in a boost::variant

Tags: c++, boost

I'm getting a warning for the following code, which dissapears if I remove boost::blank from the variant:

```
namespace DB
{
struct Value{};
struct Container{};
}

typedef boost::variant <boost::blank, DB::Value, DB::Container> CommandData;

struct Command {
    explicit Command(CommandData& _data): data(_data){
    }

    CommandData data;
};

int main()
{
    CommandData commandData;
    Command command(commandData);
    return 0;
}
```

What's this issue?

Here's the warning:

```
1>: warning C4345: behavior change: an object of POD type constructed with an initializer of the form () will be default-initialized
1>          c:\boost_1_49_0\boost\variant\variant.hpp(1224) : while compiling class template member function 'boost::variant<T0_,T1,T2>::variant(void)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T0_=boost::blank,
1>              T1=DB::Value,
1>              T2=DB::Container
1>          ]
1>          c:\code.h(38) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::variant<T0_,T1,T2>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T0_=boost::blank,
1>              T1=DB::Value,
1>              T2=DB::Container
1>          ]
```

Comment: I removed the ellipsis in your code. They have meaning in C++11 and are discouraged in samples. Please also try to provide fully compiling example code exhibiting your problem. In your case making the code compile is trivial, but you should try to reduce the friction on people answering your question as much as possible.

Comment: @pmr Updated question as requested!

Comment: I request nothing. Just showing you ways to get better answers. Anyway, you also probably want to take `_data` by `const&` or even take one of the contained values directly by `&&` and forward it onto the variant.

Comment: @pmr Thanks! If I pass _data by const, should I also add a copy constructor and an assignment operator?

Comment: No, adding a constructor does not suppress generation of the default generated functions in that case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That warning is rather dumb. [It warns that MSVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewb47ee%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) now does the right thing as opposed to some ancient version. You can turn it off with a `pragma`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not because of the variant. Try to put int as a struct member for example instead of variant, and you'll get the same warning. The thing is that variant initializes with the first value by default, and boost::blank is a spectial type to optimize the variant behavior. See the variant documentation in Boost

Comment: What type should I add to my variant to represent the idea that a Command might have no data associated with it?

Comment: You're on the right way. Use boost::blank. Bur Get rid of constructor in struct and use Command as POD data type or as @prm suggests supress this warning

Comment: But the constructor forces initialisation of the data member.

Comment: That's right it's using the first value boost::blank as default, so you can force the initialization by doing:
CommandData commandData = boost::blank();